# Getting Historical data for a single GOOG option

Tags: api, interactive-brokers

I am trying to data historical data for a single GOOG Option from IB.
My python code is:

```
ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, clientId=1)
#
contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = "GOOG"
contract.secType = "OPT"
contract.exchange= "SMART"
#contract.primaryExchange = "ISLAND"
contract.currency = "USD"
contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "20210917"
contract.strike = 2700
contract.right = "Call"
contract.multiplier = "100"
bars = ib.reqHistoricalData(contract, endDateTime='', durationStr='30 D', barSizeSetting='1 day', whatToShow='BID', useRTH=True,  formatDate=1, keepUpToDate=True)

# convert to pandas dataframe:
df = util.df(bars)
print(df)
```

I get back:
Error 162, reqId 4: Historical Market Data Service error message:No data of type EODChart is available for the exchange 'BEST' and the security type 'Option' and '30 d' and '1 day', contract: Contract(secType='OPT', symbol='GOOG', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='20210917', strike=2700, right='Call', multiplier='100', exchange='SMART', currency='USD')

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to IB's [documentation](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/historical_limitations.html), you can't access "End of Day (EOD) data for options, FOPs, warrants and structured products"